# Cannot connect to MSVSMon running on Windows 7 x64

Tags: visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

I have a test machine that runs Windows 7 Enterprise x64. I setup MSVSMon (tried both 64 and 32 bit versions) on it and made sure that the Firewall settings would not block the remote debugger. Now I'm trying to connect to this from my dev box running Windows 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2010. However when I try to connect to the remote debugger, it shows me the following error message:

"Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor named "xxxxx". THere is no server by the specified name running on the remote computer.

Some obvious things:
- I have verified that the name I'm using is correct (picked it up from teh MSMSMon.exe options dialog)
- The dev box does have access to the remote machine, I can check that by connecting to it's file shares.
- The same instance of visual studio is able to connect just fine to another similar test machine, but one running a 32 bit Windows 7 Enterprise.

Any ideas?
Vin

Comment: Are you running both sessions from the same account? Does the account have admin privileges?

Comment: Make sure you're using the full name including port number, usually serverName:4018 or 4019

Answer (score 2):

Make sure if you are debugging from VS2010,its the debugger for 2010 and not 2008, and/or vice versa

Answer (score 0):

I would check your firewall is not blocking the connection. Just because you can connect to the fileshare doesn't mean it's allowing the DCOM connection to the Remote Debugger.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I generally run MSVSMon on the remote machine from a share on my dev machine where I have several versions of Visual Studio installed. I get "There is no server by the specified name running on the remote computer" error when I run the wrong version of MSVSMon. For example if the VS2008 version of MSVMon is running on the remote machine and I am trying to attach to the process from VS2010.

Default location of MSVMon for VS2008 :

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger

Default location of MSVMon for VS2010 :

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger

Answer (score 0):

I've found alot of ppl bump into this scenario. Tried to cup the solution in my blog post:
http://livshitz.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/remote-debugging-visual-studio-unable-to-connect-to-the-microsoft-visual-studio-remote-debugging-monitor/#more-144

Here is the snippet of the solution:

- Make sure firewall is not blocking your request
- Make sure the installed version of Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor is supported by the running Visual Sutdio
- Create local user on remote target, with the exact user name and password as the debugging user (that runs VS process)
- If dns resolving is unavailable (source and target on different domains) open this file
  "c:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"
  and add a new line at the bottom:
  "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TargetHostName" (without quotes)
  This will map the target host name with an IP.